# WPF Show child menu item using shortcut key

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drop-down-menu, menuitem, submenu

## WPF Show child menu item using shortcut key

**F**ile

- New
- Open
- Save As

I would like to bind short cut key to File menu like Alt+F to show the child/sub menu itmes.I have tried many options but none of them worked.I just want to show sub menu and don't want to do any other command binding or actions.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard Shortcuts

To add a keyboard shortcut to a menu item, add a underscode "_" in front of the caracter you want to use as your hot key. This automatically sets the InputGestureText to an appropriate value. But you can also override the proposed text by setting this property to a text of your choice.